# Decision between right and left ideals of a ring?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

Let us suppose whe find a phenomenon (in nature, social sciences, whatever) for which we believe (or some author has stated) it is possible a formalization or modeling in terms of ideal of a ring. Let us further suppose, the possibility of a two-sided ideal is excluded (what specific feature of the phenomenon might exclude that?). My question is: which kind of property of the phenomenon or object of study would be responsible for the decision between a right or a left ideal of the ring? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no real reason to decide. A left ideal of a ring is the same as a right ideal of the opposite ring.

Comment: To add to Tobias's comment, it just depends on how you set up your algebraic model.  If you like writing your actions from the left, you'll probably work with left ideals.  It's like how some people like writing their functions on the left, and some people like writing them on the right.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft. Well, I assume not all phenomena are symmetric, right? I mean, could it be that a phenomenon should be formalized as a right ideal, with no opposite ring available at the natural or social description at stake?

Comment: There is always an opposite ring available, it just might not be the one you can describe "naturally". I am really not quite sure what sort of answer you are looking for. Could you provide an example of the sort of phenomenon you are interested in?

Comment: I provide you right now with some quotations which should clarify what I am looking for:  
“[…] the sublanguage grammar contains rules which the language violates and the language grammar contains rules which the sublanguage never meets. It follows that while the sentences of such science object-languages are included in the language as a whole, the grammar of these sublanguages intersects (rather than is included in) the grammar of the language as a whole.”

Comment: “Because a conjunction requires that the sentence following it have certain similarities to the sentence preceding (or, that particular kinds of sentences be further conjoined to compensate for the excess dissimilarities), each SCS…CS preserves certain properties of its initial S.

Comment: As a result, certain sublanguages, including the science languages, have, under CS, a relation to the language as a whole (in respect to all other operations on S) similar to that of a right ideal in a ring. If S1 is in the sublanguage, and S2 is not, S1 Cs S2 retains properties of S1 and is in the sublanguage. But in some cases, this holds only for those conjunctions which require strong similarities; or else it holds if the special grammatical properties of the sublanguage are defined only on the first S of each of its SCS…CS.

Comment: The import of this right-ideal type of construction is that certain subject-matter restrictions (referring thus to meaning, as against the material-implication conjoinings of sentences) are determined for every SCS...CS sequence by its first sentence (in the time order in the underlying regular form, i.e., before permutations). The possibility arises of covering the language with a system of such right-ideal-like subsets, whose intersection may be empty or may consist of certain distinguished sublanguages.” END OF QUOTE

Comment: S stands for sentence, and S por connective.....

Comment: I hope that helps you to provide a more specific answer. :)

Comment: By the way, is there a canonical way of visually representing (right or left) ideals? Something like Venn diagrams or the like?